# How to find lines that contain ONLY lowercase using grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am new to bash and am learning to use grep.

`grep ^[a-z] file.txt` will show all the lines that begin with lowercase
`grep [a-z] file.txt` all lines with lowercase

Can't figure out how to show lines with ALL lowercase, can anyone help?

Comment: You just need to end a quantifier and anchor in your first example.

Answer (score 7):

You can use anchors in your regex for `egrep`:

```
egrep '^[[:lower:]]+$' file
```

This `egrep` will only find lines that have **only lowercase letters** in the (not even space is allowed).

Comment: I would use `egrep '^[[:lower:]]+$' file` since I see that `[a-z]` may fail on multilingual system

Answer (score 4):

This will match and exclude lines that contain something else besides `a-z`.

```
cat file.txt | grep -v '[^[:lower:]]'
```

If you need to allow symbols too (this example allows `!`, `+`, `,`):

```
cat file.txt | grep -v '[^[:lower:]!+,]'
```

Comment: You don't need to `cat` and pipe, `grep ... file` suffices.

Comment: Use `grep -v '[^[:lower:]]' file`

Comment: @fedorqui: yeah, I know, but old habits die hard. When I grep for stuff, my input usually comes from some sort of command, thus the pipe :)

Comment: @Bernhard: nothing is wrong with `[a-z]`, unless you want to match some additional characters that are considered lowercase letters in some locales.

Comment: @Bernhard `[a-z]` may fail on multilingual system.  It may give uppercase letter, even if you ask for lower case letter.  Do a google search for it.  Use `[:lower`:]`.  Its should work for all.